# how to fetch value of particular row column by clicking button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flask, bootstrap-4

here is my html code

```
  <div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered">
         <thead>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Address</td>
            <td>city</td>
            <td>Pincode</td>
            <th>Options</th>
         </thead>
         
         {% for row in rows %}
            <tr>
               <td>{{row["registraion_number"]}}</td>
               <td>{{row["rc_number"]}}</td>
               <td> {{ row["owner_name"]}}</td>
               <td>{{row['state']}}</td>  
               <td><button type="button" class="use-address"></td>
            </tr>
         {% endfor %}
      </table>
      </div>
      <a href = "/">Go back to home page</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

this is my image of table coming
[image]

how to **fetch name by selecting the particular button at that row**

any help would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the extra column because you use an opening tag and not a closing tag at the end.

```
<td><button type="button" class="use-address" /><td>
                                                ^^^^
```